# How to generate random correlated uniform data from a correlation matrix?

Tags: r, dataframe, correlation, distribution, covariance

I have a very specific problem to solve that makes researching a solution quite hard because I lack the requisite math skills.

**My goal:** Given a *covariance/correlation matrix* and *variable ranges*, generate some random data. This data needs to meet 3 important conditions:

- The covariance/correlation of this data should be similar to the provided covariance/correlation matrix.
- The ranges of the variables of this data (columns) should be bounded by the provided ranges.
- Each variable has a uniform distribution.

**Is there perhaps an R package or function that can generate this data conditions using those provided arguments?** Maybe code in some other language that I could then rewrite in R?

---

EDIT1:

In the case that uniformity (condition 3) cannot be met, **is there perhaps an R package or function that can generate data that meets just conditions 1 and 2**? *In other words, I don't care what distribution the variables take.*

---

EDIT2:

Here is my first very terrible attempt at this problem. All it does so far is create positively correlated and uniform data. Tests are at the bottom:

```r
generate_correlated_variables <- function(variable_ranges, numPoints = 100, nbins = 10) {
  
  df <- matrix(0, nrow = numPoints, ncol = length(variable_ranges))
  colnames(df) <- names(variable_ranges)

  
  for (i in 1:length(variable_ranges)) {
    
    df[,i] <- runif(numPoints, min = as.numeric(variable_ranges[[i]][1]), max = as.numeric(variable_ranges[[i]][2]))  
    
  }
  
  #Sample one variable and determine how many points fall in each bin
  #These amounts will be used to sample the rest of the variables
  df[,1] <- runif(numPoints, min = as.numeric(variable_ranges[[1]][1]), max = as.numeric(variable_ranges[[1]][2]))
  bin_width <- (variable_ranges[[1]][2] - variable_ranges[[1]][1])/nbins
  breaks_vec <- seq(variable_ranges[[1]][1], variable_ranges[[1]][2], by = bin_width)
  table <- table(cut(df[,1], breaks = breaks_vec, include.lowest = TRUE))

  binned_ranges_list <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(variable_ranges))
  names(binned_ranges_list) <- names(variable_ranges)
  
  temp <- vector(mode = "list", length = nbins)
  
  
  for (i in 1:length(variable_ranges)) {

      bin_width <- (variable_ranges[[i]][2] - variable_ranges[[i]][1])/nbins
      
      breaks_vec <- seq(variable_ranges[[i]][1], variable_ranges[[i]][2], by = bin_width)
      
      for (j in 1:nbins) {
        
        temp[[j]][1] <- breaks_vec[j]
        temp[[j]][2] <- breaks_vec[j+1]
        
      }
      
      binned_ranges_list[[i]] <- temp
      
  }
  
  print(binned_ranges_list)
    
  #sample ranges
  for (i in 1:length(variable_ranges)) {
    
    sampled_values_vec <- c()
      
      for (j in 1:nbins) {
        
        sample <- runif(n = table[j], min = binned_ranges_list[[i]][[j]][1], max = binned_ranges_list[[i]][[j]][2])
        
        sampled_values_vec <- c(sampled_values_vec, sample)
        
      }
    
    df[,i] <- sampled_values_vec
    }
   return(df) 
  }
  

#Tests
variable_ranges = list(A = c(1, 100), B = c(50, 100), C = c(1, 10))

a <- generate_correlated_variables(variable_ranges = variable_ranges, numPoints = 100, nbins = 2)
cor(a)

b <- generate_correlated_variables(variable_ranges = variable_ranges, numPoints = 100, nbins = 50)
cor(b)
```

Comment: Theoretically you could do this by generating independent uniform data for each variable and then reordering some values to introduce correlations... but there's probably better ways. This might be a better question for stats.stackexchange.

Comment: Great question. This problem has a simple answer when the variables are Gaussian instead of uniform, namely: let x be a vector of N(0, 1) variables, let L L' = S be the Cholesky decomposition of the covariance matrix S, then L x is Gaussian with mean 0 and covariance S. I'm pretty sure that the property var(L x) = S holds whether x is Gaussian or not, however, L x won't be a vector of uniform variables, instead it's the sum of uniform variables, so it will be more or less bump shaped (more so the more variables there are). I don't see a way to ensure uniformity and keep the same covariance.

Comment: I second the recommendation for stats.SE.

Comment: @GregorThomas thats an interesting idea. I could use a genetic algorithm or some other optimization technique to keep reordering and resampling values until I get a similar correlation matrix. Seems pretty inefficient though haha. Also, its tricky because it potentially generates more questions than answers. What should the cost function be? And which optimization algorithm is ideal for this type of problem?

Comment: I'm beginning to think it might be impossible to match the covariance and preserve uniformity. However, I would be interested to hear what stats.SE has to say about it.

Comment: @RobertDodier I updated the question where I would accept an answer where the variables are Gaussian. If you know any R package, function, Python library, etc that does this, it would still be immensely helpful!

Comment: Okay, in that case `L <- t (chol (S))` and `x <- rnorm (n, 0, 1)` and then `y <- L %*% x` is enough to yield `y` having a Gaussian distribution with mean 0 and covariance S. You can add any vector to y to get mean equal to that vector.

Comment: @RobertDodier "might be impossible to match the covariance and preserve uniformity" Well, lets say you have source of independent bits. Take 3 bits, then 29bits and form one 32bit uniform number. Take the same 3 bits and another 29bits, and form another 32bit number. They ought to be correlated and uniform, aren't they?

Comment: @RobertDodier I posted some sample code to illustrate the idea as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the idea how to get correlated uniform random numbers.

Suppose you have source of independent bits

1. First generate array X bits (say 2 bits).
2. Then generate another random array with upper (middle, lower, some position...) bits replaced from step 1.
3. Again generate another random array with upper (middle, lower, some position...) bits replaced from step 1.

Arrays from step 2 and 3 would be uniform, but correlated.

Code for illustration (sorry, Python)

```
import numpy as np

N=1000000

rng = np.random.default_rng()

m = np.empty(N, dtype=np.uint32); m.fill(2*1073741824-1) # mask 2^31-1

f = rng.integers(low = 0, high=4294967295, size=N, dtype=np.uint32, endpoint=True)
f = f - np.bitwise_and(f, m) # upper three bits

q = rng.integers(low = 0, high=4294967295, size=N, dtype=np.uint32, endpoint=True)
z = rng.integers(low = 0, high=4294967295, size=N, dtype=np.uint32, endpoint=True)

print("Uncorrelated")
print(np.corrcoef([q, z]))

q = f + np.bitwise_and(m, q)
z = f + np.bitwise_and(m, z)

print("Correlated")
print(np.corrcoef([q, z]))
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Yes, that constructs correlated variables which are marginally uniformly distributed, but is there a way to impose a specific covariance?

Comment: @RobertDodier That is very good question. I could sample array with, say, different correlation coeff by doing the same trick with bit #13 (or bit #17, or two bits at different position, or ...). But is there a way from given specific covariance to proceed to the bit positions? I don't know.

Comment: The business about the leading bits is effectively creating 2^m square bins along the diagonal, each of which is uniformly covered by random points. The smaller the bins, the closer to the diagonal, and the larger the correlation; some example calculations suggest the correlation is 1 - 1/2^(2 m) (in two dimensions at least). It seems like one could get other correlation values by relaxing the bin sizes so they can be different. The presence of larger bins decreases the correlation.

Comment: One could, I guess, let one bin be bigger, and then divide up the rest into equal sized bins, then search over the bigger bin size to find the size which gives the desired correlation. It seems like that should work in more than two dimensions as well.